# Binomial-like distribution with shifting probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose a student answers a question from a teacher, his probability of getting the question right is **p**, for each successive answer he gets right, **p** is reduced by **r** because the teacher decides to make the problem more difficult. The questions the teacher prepared however has a cap in difficulty, so after **s** successive correct answers the probability will no longer reduce further. If the student gets a question wrong, the difficulty resets to **p**.

The teacher challenges the student to correctly answer **k** questions in a row.

1. What is the probability that the student will complete this task within **n** tries?
2. What is the mean number of tries required to complete this task?

Comment: What happens when the student misses a question? Does the difficulty reset? And what is $n$, exactly, the number of attempts to *answer* or the number of attempted *strings* of answers? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Reset yes sorry I forgot to mention. Haven't tried anything outside simulation with program.

Comment: In the case of strings of answers, the problem is simple. Assume $s \geq k$, then the probability that a given string of answers is successful is $\prod_{i=0}^{s-1} (p-ir) \prod_{i=s}^k (p-sr)$. (When $s< k$ the second product is no longer required.) Then the number of strings of answers required is a geometric random variable with this probability.

Comment: What seems to be a bit more difficult is to identify the distribution of the length of a string of answers. I can see a recursive algorithm for how to compute this distribution, because we can explicitly write down $P(N \geq n)$ as a product (similar to what we did before). But I can't immediately see a simple formula for the PMF.

Comment: Yea the question is easier if you just calculate the probability of successfully getting every question right in a length of k questions since it's just product of each successive probability. But that's not the question xD

Comment: Yes, except that you can marginalize to split the question into these two separate problems: what is the distribution of the number of strings required, and what is the distribution of the length of a single string. Then the distribution of the number of attempted questions before a successful string is a sum of a random number of random variables. Its expectation is then easy to compute by Wald's identity. Computing its actual *distribution* is a more difficult matter but can still be done using the total probability formula and some combinatorics.

Comment: All I know is the first one can be calculated by sum((n+1)*(p*q^n)), n=0...infinite